# ConEmu: Keyboard shortcut to run "cls[ENTER]"

Tags: conemu

In ConEmu, is it possible to create a Macro to type/paste "cls" then press [ENTER] and (ideally) assign it the keyboard shortcut [CTRL]+L ?

I am trying to emulate the clear screen function of the Linux Shell but for the Windows Command Prompt/PowerShell.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use GuiMacro (Keys & Macro page)

```
print("\ecls\n")
```

"\e" emulates Esc express, "\n" emulates Enter.

Of course, you may assign this macro to any desirable hotkey.

Comment: Brillant, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Clink](https://code.google.com/p/clink/), it provides full Readline experience (including Ctrl+L and history search). Works great with ConEmu too.

Comment: Clink does NOT works with powershell.