# Clear console buffer in ConEmu with Cygwin

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin, conemu

I've recently switched from using [iterm](https://iterm2.com/) in OSX to using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) in [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) on Windows.  One thing I'm really missing is the ability to completely clear the terminal buffer at any time using Alt+k.  I've managed to get Alt+k to clear the buffer using a GuiMacro in ConEmu to run the command `cmd /c cls` using this approach:

[ConEmu: Keyboard shortcut to run "cls[ENTER]"](https://superuser.com/questions/623826/conemu-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-clsenter)

The problem is that because it's a command, it doesn't work when I've just kicked off a process.  The same limitation applies to Ctrl+l, which clears the current window but leaves the scrollback buffer in tact.  What I'm really after is a way to completely clear the scrollback buffer at any time using a keyboard shortcut.  Any ideas?

I'd also be interested to a lesser degree in doing the same thing in bash on linux (as I run it in a VM) and in the regular Windows cmd.exe.

**Update:** This seems to be possible when using the terminal in my IDE (Intellij), on all platforms.  Unfortunately other limitations of running the terminal inside my IDE mean this isn't the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Why are you trying to run "cmd" from cygwin?? Ctrl+L clears cygwin screen. At that does not relate to ConEmu at all.

Comment: I've had to use `cmd` to be able to clear the scrollback buffer, I haven't found another way of doing this in Cygwin alone.  Or in bash in Ubuntu either, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

This clears scrollback buffer in cygwin bash

```
clear
```

or

```
echo -e '\0033\0143'
```

Comment: OK great, `echo -e '\0033\0143'` clears the buffer in the same way as `cmd /c cls`, but is better as I don't need to shell out to cmd.   I still can't use it whilst another command is running, however - do you know of a way to make that possible?

Comment: You must not do that. When another command is running, any significant modification of buffer may damage program output, or even lead to its crush.

Comment: But I've never had a problem with exactly that behaviour in iTerm, where it is standard. I'd like to replicate that useful behaviour on other platforms.

Comment: **Update**: Not sure if this changed recently, but `clear` does not work (any more?). The echo sequence still does clear the scrollback buffer though. I'm _almost_ sure `clear` worked until recently, until I installed the latest conEmu update.

Comment: Working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The developer has addressed this: https://conemu.github.io/en/ClearScreen.html

Answer (score 0):

- Go to

  > Settings -> Keys & Macro
- Select Macros in dropdown menu
- Choose an empty Macro
- Set key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Set GUI Macro to

  ```
  print("echo -e \"\\0033\\0143\"\n")
  ```
- Save settings

Comment: This doesn't address the problem as it only works when the prompt is available, not when a foreground application is running.  iterm2 on OSX is able to clear the entire buffer, and handles the situations described by the dev linked in Scott Coldwell's answer.  This behaviour is what I'm after.

The use case for this is a long-running application which is printing logs to the console; I want to test the application, but want to clear the logs before performing some action, so I know all the logs relate only to that action.  Also I've already linked this solution in the question.